# run kafka producer from my local gives me Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to stream data from Twitter and store in a topic. I am using single broker everything is set up on one server. I am using ec2 instance and configured `listeners = PLAINTEXT://aws_private_ip:9092` and `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://aws_private_ip:9092`, everything is working fine when trying to send and receive messages from the ec2 instance.

But when I try to run producer from my local windows to stream Twitter data I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException:
>   Failed to send messages after 3 tries

Did I miss anything? I am able to telnet from my local system to the ec2 instance with 2181 and 9092 port. Do I need to configure public IP anywhere?

Note: the same producer and consumer code are running as expected in my local ubuntu VM, but getting above error when using aws ec2. I opened all the security groups ports.

Comment: Try to increase `retry.backoff.ms` from the default 100 ms to 1000 ms, `message.send.max.retries` from the default 5 to e.g. 10 and `topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms` to 0. Also, which kafka version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me what are the properties I need to connect to create in server.properties and to connect producer from local to aws ec2., my kafka version is

Comment: If you are using Java you just need to pass the aforementioned parameters in `Properties` object using e.g. `properties.put("retry.backoff.ms", "1000");`

Comment: my java code is correct it is working in my local to stream twitter data. I am very new to coding , my question is  what are the parameters to configure in kafka broker ie server.properties to connect , my java producer from local windows eclipse.

Comment: Set `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://aws_public_ip:9092` and retry.